# No subscribers registered for event class error - Greenrobot

Tags: android, android-activity, event-bus, greenrobot-eventbus

I am getting this warning and the code written in my event subscriber is not triggered always.. it is very random.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks.

[image]

I have this class which posts the event...
`EventListAdapter`:

```
protected void updateDbToHandle(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
  //something here....
  toggleEvent.setContext(context);
  EventBus.getDefault().post(toggleEvent);
}

protected void updateDbToIgnore(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
  //something here....
  toggleEvent.setContext(context);
  EventBus.getDefault().post(toggleEvent);
}
```

`Event class`:

```
public class ToggleEvent {
  private String name;
  private Context context;

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public Context getContext() {
    return context;
  }

  public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
}
```

and `the subscriber`:

```
public class ToggleEventListener {

  public ToggleEventListener() {
    super();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
  }

  public void onEvent(ToggleEvent toggleEvent) {
    Log.d("toggleEvent", "toggle event triggered in event bus");
    Context context = toggleEvent.getContext();
    Intent intentForRinger = new Intent(context, RingerToggler.class);
    System.out.println("change in calendar is here ");
    //calRead.getEventControl(context);
    intentForRinger.putExtra("START_TIME", false);
    intentForRinger.putExtra("RESCAN", false);
    intentForRinger.putExtra("CHANGE", true);
    intentForRinger.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startService(intentForRinger);
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
  }
}
```

Not sure why I get this warning...
and also my code written inside the toggle event is not executed everytime..
it is getting missed and it is very random that the event is invoked...

Comment: You are unsubscribing from the event after you receive it the first time. You typically only do that at the end of the lifetime of your event listener class.

Comment: @Brian I sort of got that when I was going through different other posts here., But I am not sure where to put it so that to make sure it is executed once at the end and the event is unregistered.. I couldn't find a solid example anywhere.. and also do the subscriber need to extend any class so that we get methods like onCreate(), onDestroy() which will be executed by default. your help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: I added the unregister() to finalize() seems like it is working. Let me test some more cases. Thanks for your insight. @Brain

Comment: So the "typical" usage would be to implement the listener on an activity and subscribe during on create and unsubscribe during on destroy.

Comment: In my case the events are triggered from a CursorAdapter class and my operations are background like updating database and changing AlamManager so I couldn't bring it to an activity as there is no screen involved in this.